# React Native ListView Filtering

Tags: reactjs, listview, react-native

I'm using React-native and I have an issue that I can't solve.

I have a list(ListView) with x elements and the user is able to filter this list on different dates. When the user chooses dates I filter the list and call this.setState() from an `onClick` in render.

This gives me:
"Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`."

I get this because I have a button in the render method that call setState.

I tried with `componentWillMount`, `componentWillUpdate`, `componentDidUpdate` but it doesn't work.

```
<Accordion
  sections={this.state.uniqueAvailableTimeSlots}
  renderHeader={this.renderAccordionHeader}
  renderContent={this.renderAccordionBody}
  onChange={this.onChange()}
/>

//OnChange will be called when a filter is choosen
//I filter a list and put it in filteredTimeSlots
onChange = () => {
  const filteredTimeSlots = this.state.availableTimeSlots.filter((timeSlot) => {
    return timeSlot.timeSlot.includes(this.state.uniqueAvailableTimeSlots[index]);
  });
  //I set the state for the new list
  this.setState({
    availableTimeSlotsFiltered: this.state.availableTimeSlotsFiltered.cloneWithRows(filteredTimeSlots)
  });

}
```

Comment: You should show some code, if you want to get help

Comment: Show the code of the Button. I guess it's something like 
`onClick={this.setState()}` ?

Comment: I added a code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here `onChange={this.onChange()}`

It should be `onChange={ this.onChange }`

You are calling the function in the props, therefore the Warning message.

Comment: No, this didn't help. I still receive the same error.

Comment: If you want help you should post more code.  The snippet you posted is not valid in any react environment.  Post the entire component file